# Stop Debugging (Shift+F5) causing debugging to restart

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition for development. I have observed that whenever I test web applications or websites using Ctrl+F5 and **then stop the debugging** (or close the browser), the debugging starts again, as if I pressed Ctrl+F5 again.

Initially I thought this could be because of a sticky ctrl key but I have checked and confirmed that sticky keys in my machine are not enabled.

I searched on the web and have observed that many others have also faced the very same issue. But Microsoft says that the issue is due to a sticky ctrl key. (Refer : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534915/stop-debugging-shortcut-key-shift-f5-causes-debugging-to-restart-instead-of-just-stopping)

Anyone else has any other ideas as to why this could be happening (in case I might have missed out on some updated forum)

Thanks a lot.! :)

Comment: Happens with Visual studio 2010 as well

Comment: And Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like your question as this occurs to me occasionally and don't know why after many years & don't believe it's related to sticky keys.

There are only two ways I can stop the debugging in this situation:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>; <kbd>E</kbd>   = I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>; to open the Debug menu then <kbd>E</kbd> for 'Stop Debugging' This is alternative hotkey combination that will work.
2. is to click the stop button on the debug tool bar.
3. (optional) Sometimes when I'm not able to press teh <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> I'm not able to get focus to the toolbar and I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> 5 times. Somehow the sticky keys get stuck even though I didn't turn them on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Catto, When I'm using the debugging menus to stop the debugging, it doesn't restart. But when I use the shortcut to stop debugging (shift-F5), the debugging restarts.

Anyway, thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I too have this happen to me sometimes, and I too have disabled StickyKeys.  I even see this sometimes when I have locked my computer.  When this happens and I try to type in my password, the computer acts like I am pressing down control.

My only suggestion is to use the menus to stop Debugging, and then gently tap the Control key twice, and then try again.  It always stops when I do this.

In the back of my mind, I wonder if it is due to conflicts of third-party utilities that intercept key combos for their triggers.  SnagIt, Freesnap, AutoHotKey are three that I use, but when the problem is so intermittent, you can't really disable them and say, "yup, my problem went away."

Answer (score 0):

This may sound simple and might not be the answer for you but it was for me. Somehow in Visual Studio 2015 my Shift+F5 got mapped to "Debug.Restart" and "Debug.StopDebugging" got remapped to Ctrl+Alt+Break. Not sure if Resharper somehow screwed up the shortcuts.

I was able to fix it by going to Tools... Options... Environment... Keyboard, searching for "Debug.StopDebugging" and assigning Shift+F5 to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I'm also using Visual  Studio 2008. Just click tools>>option>>environment>>Keyboard. And then set

[image: this option]

to "Default".

Comment: I wonder why this answer was with -1 points. It worked for me with VS 2019

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I upgraded VS to that disaster 16.6.x which changed Shift-F5 from Debug.stop to Debug.start.

Tools menu > Options > Keyboard fixes it.  (It's a confusing dialog but you'll figure it out -- you're a programmer, ie IQ through the roof, right?  Yeah!

Shift-Ctrl-F5 does restart.

I'm in my 50th year of programming and still loving it and making tons of money.
What a career this is!